# Save matching values into a variable

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables

I'm trying to script a "password expiry notification". I collect all users in our AD and put the date, where the password expires into an array. Now my idea is to check if todays date + 4 days is matching with one or more values from the array. It returns "Exists"

Now my question is: How can I save the matching dates/values into a variable?

```
$Users =@()
$Users += Get-ADUser @QueryParameters | Select-Object -Property $SelectionProperties

for($i = 0; $i -lt $Users.Count; $i ++)
{
    $a = $Users[$i].PasswordExpiry
    $a
}

$today = (get-date).AddDays(4).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')

if ($Users.PasswordExpiry -contains $today)
{
    write-host "Exists"
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no AD property `PasswordExpiry`. You will have to calculate that from `PasswordLastSet`, and the value of what you get from `(Get-ADDefaultDomainpasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge` taking into account the user properties `PasswordNeverExpires` and `PasswordExpired`

Comment: What is it gonna help you to know that today+4 exists among _any_ of the expiration dates? Are you planning on sending 1 single email with the entire company in CC? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Where-Object` to filter out all the users except for those who's passwords expire within 4 days, then send an email to each of those:

```
$now = Get-Date
$threshold = $now.AddDays(4).Date

$expiringUsers = Get-ADUser @QueryParameters | Where-Object { $_.PasswordExpiry -gt $now -and $_.PasswordExpiry -le $threshold }

foreach($user in $expiringUsers){
    $expiryDate = $_.PasswordExpiry
    Send-MailMessage -From noreply@domain.tld -To $user.Mail -SmtpServer smtphost.domain.tld -Subject "Password about to expire!" -Body "Your password will expire on '$expiryDate'! Change it today!"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. 

Is there any possibility, that I can write the matching values in a variable?
I already have the "code" to write a Teams message, but it requires, that I get these dates in a variable. 

Like; check, if todays date + 4 days exists in the array and write all matching values into a variable

Comment: @DonTxm Why is it important with a separate variable? Just reference `$user.PasswordExpiry` inside the loop when you need the expiry date for the current user